# discord.py remove_roles isn't working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, discord, discord.py

I have a bot for auto permissions for Fortnite KD Ranking. It works like;

> If user have 1+ KD bot will assign the user "Bronz" perm.
>
> If user have 1.5+ KD bot will assign the user "Gümüş" perm.
>
> If user have 2+ KD bot will assign the user "Altın" perm.

and it works like a charm. BUT. Bot must be remove the old role when it ranking up the next perm. So I mean, if a user rank up the "Altın" perm. The old perm "Gümüş" must be removed but `remove.roles` is not working.

Here is bunch of codes for those lines:

```
    for list in LISTE:
        roles = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=list)
        await client.remove_roles(message.author, role)
    await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
elif ratio >= BRONZE_B and ratio <= BRONZE_E:
    role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=LISTE[2])

    embed=discord.Embed(color=0xcd8032)
    embed.add_field(name="Oyuncu", value=username, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="KD", value=str(ratio), inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Lig", value=LISTE[2], inline=True)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, embed = embed)

    embed2=discord.Embed(color=0x727272)
    embed2.add_field(name="Sonraki Lig", value=LISTE[3], inline=True)
    embed2.add_field(name="Hedef KD", value=str(SILVER_B), inline=True)
    embed2.set_footer(text="Lig verileriniz Fortnite KD değerlerinize göre güncellendi.")
    await client.send_message(message.channel, embed = embed2)

    for list in LISTE:
        roles = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=list)
        await client.remove_roles(message.author, role)
    await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
elif ratio >= SILVER_B and ratio <= SILVER_E:
    role = discord.utils.get(message.server.roles, name=LISTE[3])

    embed=discord.Embed(color=0x727272)
    embed.add_field(name="Oyuncu", value=username, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="KD", value=str(ratio), inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Lig", value=LISTE[3], inline=True)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, embed = embed)

    embed2=discord.Embed(color=0xcfb223)
    embed2.add_field(name="Sonraki Lig", value=LISTE[4], inline=True)
    embed2.add_field(name="Hedef KD", value=str(GOLD_B), inline=True)
    embed2.set_footer(text="Lig verileriniz Fortnite KD değerlerinize göre güncellendi.")
    await client.send_message(message.channel, embed = embed2)
```

If I use `replace_roles` instead of `remove_roles` it seems work but this time It removes the ALL roles and replace it with the higher rank perm.

I mean when I use `replace_roles` if a Moderatör check his rank with my bot command `/derece`, bot takes his all roles and gives him higher KD rank perm.

I want it work like this;

> If user have 1+ KD bot will assign the user "Bronz" perm.
>
> If user rank up to 1.5+ KD remove `Bronz` perm and give `Silver` perm
>
> If user rank up to 2+ KD remove `Silver` perm and give `Gold` perm

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Doing simultaneously remove_roles and add_roles doesnt work. Instead you need to use replace_roles. For replace_roles to work like that, you first need to get all the roles from a user, then iterate throught that list and remove the ones you dont want and add the ones you want, and then call replace_roles with that list. This way it wont remove old roles that you didnt specify.

Comment: Documentation here: http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.replace_roles . With regards to `remove_roles` and `add_roles` not working together, is this because they both rely on receiving a Websocket event?

Answer (score 0):

Like the other user has mentioned, `replace_roles` works by removing all roles and then adding the one you want.

My workaround for this is to simply add the higher role to a user while keeping the lower roles. You can change the order/privileges of roles in the Server Settings, such that the higher role takes precedence and thus each user has the correct role colour.

[image: Role management]